# Many left joins on subqueries, need some way to increase performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is an example of my query as it stands. I have at most, approximately 10 of these joins/subqueries all of basically the same format, but with different joins and where clauses.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mytable.label, tableA.counter, tableB.counter
FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter, label
        FROM mytable
        ...joins...
        ...where...
        GROUP BY label) tableA 
    ON tableA.label=mytable.label
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter, label
        FROM mytable
        ...joins...
        ...where...
        GROUP BY label) tableB 
    ON tableB.label=mytable.label
...
```

It's taking about 2-4 seconds and this is a high-traffic page, so that kind of speed isn't good enough. Can anyone recommend a way to improve performance here?

Comment: Try using [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to [understand](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) where the choke points are. Adding indexes where appropriate should help. If you need further help, you should include the EXPLAIN output and CREATE TABLE for each table.

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on all columns that are involved in a `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, or `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I would look at the individual performance of each of you derived tables and make sure they run optionally by themselves.  Also, sometimes you can index and persist aggeragte values for quick reads via views, you can look into that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to `GROUP` here, as you're only returning 1 value.  Try a subquery approach like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.label,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter FROM tableA A WHERE A.blah = T.blah) as AValue,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) as counter FROM tableB B WHERE B.blah = T.blah) as BValue
FROM mytable T
```

Comment: That is so, so much better. Thank you! Down to half a second execution time. By any chance, do you have any SQL performance books you'd recommend?

Comment: I don't, but I know Pinal Dave has written some books.  That dude knows his stuff.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/sql-server-books/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jon Tirjan's solution, i'd share another one via using [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) and [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140308.aspx) table.

```
SELECT [A], [B]
FROM (
    SELECT 'A' AS TableName, COUNT(id) as counter
    FROM tableA 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' AS TableName, COUNT(id) as counter
    FROM tableB
) AS DT
PIVOT(SUM(counter) FOR TableName IN([A], [B])) AS PVT
```